# CollapsingToolbarLayout not work on android 4.2.2

Tags: android, layout

I have problem with collapsing toolbar.

this code work on android 5+ but not work on android 4.2.2
whats wrong with this code?

Thanks.

**Coordinator Layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#d25100">
```

**AppBar**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="#d25100">
```

**Collapsing Toolbar**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
```

**Toolbar**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

**Custom view**

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/Container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:baselineAligned="false">
```

**Tablayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabTextColor="#ffc29c"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="#e15600" />
```

**View Pager**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nilesh..

thats work for scrolling up..

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:background="#ffffff" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

but, i got blank in view pager and tab layout can not swipe.
i use view pager for fragment..

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new PagerAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```